# How to load a production create-react-app script inside an html page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've created a create-react-app simple application (as a lib) and want to load it inside an HTML page as an external script.

1. I created a create-react-app with the command `npx create-react-app my-lib`
2. Changed `my-lib/src/index.js` to this:

[image]

3. Inside the `my-lib` directory I run `yarn build`. This generated the following production files:

[image]

4. Created an external HTML file loading the production version of `my-lib`.

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: I see there are two chunks. `main` and `2.js`. So in which chunk the `AssetsManager` class is packaged?

Comment: @PrakashSharma The `AssetsManager` class is defined in the `src/App.js` file. And the `src/App.js` file is located in the `main.[hash].chunk.js`, as you can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/production-build).

Comment: Although, the build ready-to-deploy versions that we create by running -usually- `npm run build` was not meant for this kind of use cases: `const a = new AssetsManager()`, what are you trying to achieve by doing that?!

Comment: @SultanH. Thats not true. uglify won't change the property name.

Comment: @SultanH. I want to develop a modal that can be called via a callback function (this is my-lib here).  I want to pass this callback function to another application, but I don't want to use in the npm package format.

Comment: Will you add this `setInterval(() => { console.log(AssetsManager) }, 1000);` to the script where you are defining `a`, I am considering the initial load time of the script is larger than the time where `const a = ....` is ran. if that `console.log` at some point of time gave anything else but `undefined` then the initial load time would be the problem.

Comment: @SultanH. If the script isn't `async` or `defer` then browser will wait for the entire script to load and run before going further. So that should not be an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Production build creates 2 JS files i.e. chunk.js and main.js so we need to import both in index.html file

1. Loaded react component in variable and assigned to window

[image]

2. Called same window variable in index.html

[image]

Please try this way

Comment: @Punnet Bhandari, what is the above script in the fifth line? `!function (1)...`

Comment: @PabloDarde this came in index.html when i created production build, refer https://pastebin.com/9ZVr0YEM

Comment: Thanks, @Puneet Bhandari, this approach worked for me.

Comment: @PabloDarde Great

Answer (score 1):

The `create-react-app` build is creating two chunks. `main.js` and `2.js`. The `2.js` chunk contain the vendor related files and `main.js` contains your app code. To run the app you need to import both the bundles in your `html` file with `2.js` file imported before `main.js` because the vendor files are required to run your app code.

`create-react-app` also creates an `index.html` file after building which contain all the imports correctly. So I would recommend to use that `index.html` file only and do the necessary changes in that file only.

Comment: I added these two js files in the correct order but nothing changed to me.

Comment: I would recommend to use the `index.html` file created by the `create-react-app` and make necessary changes in that file only.